# Always run tasks associated with other tasks

Tags: ansible

I split an ansible role into installation and (optional) uninstallation tasks. And I want "init" work to be done before those tasks.

`playbook.yml`:

```yaml
- hosts: all
  roles:
    - role: app1
      tags: app1
    - role: app2
      tags: app2
```

`roles/app1/tasks/install.yml`:

```yaml
- ansible.builtin.debug: msg='installing a...'
  tags: app1-install-a

- ansible.builtin.debug: msg='installing b...'
  tags: app1-install-b
```

`roles/app1/tasks/uninstall.yml`:

```yaml
- ansible.builtin.debug: msg='uninstalling b...'
- ansible.builtin.debug: msg='uninstalling a...'
```

`roles/app1/tasks/main.yml`:

```yaml
# init                      <----- I would like this to always run
- block:
  - ansible.builtin.debug: msg='validate something...'
  - ansible.builtin.debug: msg='prepare something...'
  - ansible.builtin.debug: msg='do something...'
  tags: app1-install, app1-uninstall

# install
- ansible.builtin.import_tasks: install.yml
  tags: app1-install

# uninstall
- ansible.builtin.include_tasks: uninstall.yml
  when: "'app1-uninstall' in ansible_run_tags"
  tags: app1-uninstall
```

As shown in `roles/app/tasks/main.yml` I want the init tasks to always run. When I run the complete playbook, then they are run. And when I run tags `app1`, `app1-install` or `app1-uninstall`, then they are run.

But when I run a tag such as `app-install-a`, then they are skipped.

*How do I force those init tasks to always run (even without specifying them by tag)?* Put another way: I want them to run if execution enters that file.

(I could use `tags: always` but then they would run even for different roles, e.g. `app2`.)

UPDATE:
Not possible according to accepted answer, so workaround is to more init tasks into `install.yml` and `uninstall.yml` files (I wanted to avoid this duplication, but there's no other way).

Comment: You misunderstood the answer that was given to you: _Nothing shows the init tasks should run always_ > on the _"init"_ block, you should have [`tags: always`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbook_guide/playbooks_tags.html#special-tags-always-and-never)

Comment: @β.εηοιτ.βε I did understand, and you guys misunderstood me... I **desired** those tasks to always run. But in **reality**, they do not. :-)

Comment: Edited Q for clarity

Comment: Mhm, this is because `tags: app1` on your role prevent them to. Just drop it and you'll be good to go.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Q: ***"As shown in roles/app/tasks/main.yml the init tasks should always run."***

A: Nothing shows the init tasks should run always. They run on tags `app1-install, app1-uninstall` and on the inherited tag `app1`.

---

Q: ***"When I run a tag such as `app-install-a`, they (the init tasks) are skipped."***

A: This is correct.

---

Q: ***"How do I force those init tasks to always run ... ? (I could use tags: always but then they would run even for different roles, e.g. app2.)"***

A: Either you select tasks always or not. There is no such combination of tags to select tasks always except for some tag(s).

---

**Use case**

In a playbook, selectively run multiple roles. In each role, tag tasks. Some task(s) tag *always*. For example,

```yaml
shell> cat roles/app1/tasks/main.yml
- debug:
    msg: Init
  tags: always

- debug:
    msg: Install
  tags: app1-install

- debug:
    msg: Uninstall
  tags: app1-uninstall
```

```yaml
shell> cat roles/app2/tasks/main.yml
- debug:
    msg: Init
  tags: always

- debug:
    msg: Install
  tags: app2-install

- debug:
    msg: Uninstall
  tags: app2-uninstall
```

**Solution**

Instead of tags, to select roles

```yaml
shell> cat pb.yml
- hosts: all

  roles:

    - role: app1
      tags: app1
    - role: app2
      tags: app2
```

, declare a list of selected roles. For example,

```yaml
shell> cat pb.yml
- hosts: all

  roles:

    - role: app1
      when: "'app1' in run_roles|d('')|split(',')"
    - role: app2
      when: "'app2' in run_roles|d('')|split(',')"
```

Now, you can select both roles and tasks and keep running some tasks always. For example,

```yaml
shell> ansible-playbook pb.yml -t app2-uninstall -e run_roles=app2 -i localhost,

PLAY [all] ******************************************************************************

TASK [app1 : debug] ***************************************************************************
skipping: [localhost]

TASK [app2 : debug] ***************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => 
  msg: Init

TASK [app2 : debug] ***************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => 
  msg: Uninstall

PLAY RECAP ************************************************************************************
localhost: ok=2    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=1    rescued=0    ignored=0
```